# Chartjs: How to programatically remove (unhighlight or make inactive) all the active points on chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using Chart.js ver: 2.9.3. I am using custom tooltip to show up on the click of the `bubble` type `dataset`. Please refer below image:
[image]
Now, I want to unhighlight (make inactive) all the bubbles programatically on the click of the button.
Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Please share the code or a jsfiddle showing the issue. What have you tried? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As show in the code snippet below, I used [`update`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/api/#updatemode) method of the chart to rerender the chart after I set empty array for the `active` property of the chart.

**JS:**

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  ....
  .....
});

function setInactiveAllPoints() {
  myChart.active = [];
  myChart.update();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="setInactiveAllPoints()">Set Inactive All Points On Chart</button>
```